# Spark cluster mode. Deployment of application jar

Tags: maven, apache-spark, deep-learning

I want to run a maven project in spark cluster mode. I have the application jar file. I also have one master and 6 workers in working condition. But when I execute the jar application, the work is not getting distributed among the workers. The following is the command I gave from the spark directory.

```
 ./bin/spark-submit --class org.deeplearning4j.mlp.MnistMLPExample --master spark://115.145.173.152:7077 --driver-memory 10g /home/hadoop/Niki/mnist/target/dl4j-spark-0.7-SNAPSHOT-bin.jar.
```

If I add another parameter `--deploy-mode cluster`, Then its throwing exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: --deploy-mode
```

Can anyone help me out. Thanks a lot

Comment: Try --master yarn-cluster

Comment: But I am not using yarn.. where i have to use this exactly?

Comment: What kind of cluster you are using ? Is it not Hadoop cluster managed by Yarn ? If it is Hadoop cluster then please try : ./bin/spark-submit --class org.deeplearning4j.mlp.MnistMLPExample --master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 10g /home/hadoop/Niki/mnist/target/dl4j-spark-0.7-SNAPSHOT-bin.jar.

Comment: Hi I changed the order of the parameters. The previous error is solved. But now, even though I have my jar file, its giving me error like "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hadoop/Niki/mnist/target/dl4j-spark-0.7-SNAPSHOT-bin.jar (No such file or directory)".  Should I have the jar file in all the worker nodes as well?

Comment: I suggest that you run `spark-submit` without any argument and **read the instructions displayed**. Especially about the command-line option `--jars` which is (surprise!) used to ship some custom JARs to the executors, and add it to the CLASSPATH automatically.

Comment: @NikithaJV Could you please write **full** command which is throwing exception? I think that the order of properties is broken, but it's hard to say without full command :)

Comment: thanks so much Gawada. As you said. i have misordered the parameters. Anyways I made few changes in the conf/sprak-env.sh. It is working fine. But using only one worker even though I have 6 workers. I guess its many be i am using small dataset. Thansk alot for the help

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nikitha yes you need jar file in all worker nodes because spark transformations and actions will execute on worker nodes and if they use this path they search file in there local path so distribute it on all worker nodes also Can you please tell why you use this jar file path in spark code.

Comment: Hello sandeep. thanks for the reply. I copied the entire folder of my project along with the jar file in all the worker nodes (6). But still I am getting the same file not found exception.    I am trying to run deep learning algorithm in spark. I have the code in java and built using mavan. The building is success and it is running perfectly in the master node. But i want the application to get distributed over the workers. that is y I am struggling with the code now. Can you please help me out

Comment: you can do one this add that jar into your maven package so it will available in ur application jar and check that what is path of that jar in ur application jar and add that path to ur code.

Answer (score 0):

You are running spark in standalone mode. There is no cluster/client mode in standalone. It is relvent in yarn only.